# Tabulator: Can tabulator filter Parent and Child rows at the same time?

Tags: tabulator

Can tabulator filter Parent and Child rows at the same time?

I tried a quick lab set up and it did not appear to work.

I tried a simple mock up with a couple of parent rows only and a couple of parent rows with child rows "_children" and it only filtered the rows with matches in the parent rows.